# Confused by different output from iptables -L

Tags: iptables

I keep following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-using-ip-tables-on-ubuntu-12-04) tutorial using a bash shell on ubuntu 12.04 as I open more and more ports on my server. I usually open up ports like this

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport PortNumberToOpen -j ACCEPT
```

Then I use this rule to close off remaining traffic

```
sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

Normally if I then do `sudo iptables -L` it show a rule at the end of Input like this

```
 DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

But this time when I do `sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP; sudo iptables -L` it is not showing this DROP rule. I am following the exact same steps. What is going on?

Answer (score 3):

I seriously doubt `sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP` produce the ending DROP rule. In fact, `-P` sets the policy, and the policy is found in the headers of the table:

```
sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

What you may have done is `sudo iptables -A INPUT -j DROP` which indeed produce the effect you have seen:

```
➜  src  sudo iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
➜  src  sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```